# Sporadic semaphore timeout using SQL Server 2014 and pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I have this strange semaphore timeout issue when inserting into SQL Server. Below is a short snippet of code that can reproduce the issue.

None of my colleagues running the same code base have issues with the database. We also have an app server that can stay connected to the database for hours without issues. The things that are different running on my laptop are: 1) I have the newest Dell Precision 5530 which is different to my colleagues; 2) I'm using the latest copy of Anaconda/Python 3.7/pyodbc 4.0.26/Windows 10 while my colleagues are on python 3.5/3.6/Windows 7&Linux. Googling around suggested that I try updating my network adapter driver which I've tried and am on the latest driver.

Has anyone seen a similar issue?

[EDIT 1] Thanks to suggestions below, I've updated to a newer driver with a different error.

```
import time
import pyodbc

cxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=db;DATABASE=db;Uid=user;Pwd=password', autocommit=True)

def insert(cxn):
    ids = [(i, ) for i in range(100000)]
    cur = cxn.cursor()
    cur.fast_executemany = True
    cur.execute('create table #tmp (unique_id int)')
    # cur.commit()
    print(1)
    cur.executemany('insert into #tmp values (?)', ids)
    # cur.commit()
    print(2)
    cur.execute('create unique index tmp_pk on #tmp (unique_id)')
    # cur.commit()
    print(3)
    cur.execute('select * from #tmp')
    print(4)
    cur.execute('drop table #tmp')

for i in range(1000):
    print('loop {} {}'.format(i, time.time()))
    insert(cxn)
    time.sleep(60)
```

After many iterations in ipython:

```
loop 6 1557992375.617378
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8ceea4a06017> in <module>
     23 for i in range(1000):
     24         print('loop {} {}'.format(i, time.time()))
---> 25         insert(cxn)
     26         time.sleep(60)

<ipython-input-1-8ceea4a06017> in insert(cxn)
     11         # cur.commit()
     12         print(1)
---> 13         cur.executemany('insert into #tmp values (?)', ids)
     14         # cur.commit()
     15         print(2)

OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')
```

The error is :

> [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] TCP Provider:
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> (10060) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')

Comment: You're also using the wrong driver. You're using the [*deprecated* native client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) instead of [the ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-api/odbc-api-implementation-details?view=sql-server-2017). The [Python examples in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017) use the ODBC driver

Comment: You can find the latest version of the ODBC driver [here](currently [at v 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). The current version is 17. The connection string should look like this:`'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PWD=password`

Comment: *facepalm* I didn't realise this. Have just installed v17. Will let you know how it went. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a client bug but don't expect a fix. The native client [is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) :

> Important
>
> The SQL Server Native Client (SQLNCLI) remains deprecated and it is not recommended to use it for new development work.

Microsoft recommends ODBC for quite some time now and puts most of its effort there. That's quite understandable, since that's the only thing that will work on Linux.

The SQL Server documentation site contains an entire section on [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) with examples for both [pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017) and [pymssql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/python-sql-driver-pymssql?view=sql-server-2017). As they explain :

> However, Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver.

You can find the ODBC drivers for Windows, MacOS and various Linux distributions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

The example for `pyodbc` is straightforward and doesn't require a DSN :

```
import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: Ok, ODBC v17 driver didn't fix it. I've updated the above question with the new error.

Comment: In my code base, it always seem to fail at an insert to a tmp table similar to the above so I'm skeptical as to whether it's genuinely a connection issue. I also have an active SQL Server Management Studio running without dropping out

Comment: @swmfg that's a different error altogether. It complains about a failed connection. This error should appear when you call `connect` though, not after a while. BTW, where do you *close* the cursor? Your test creates 100 *Million* cursors without closing them, on the same connection. What does SQL Server's Activity Monitor and Log show?

Comment: I was under the impression that cursors close itself when it falls out of scope, but in my code I wrap cursors in a `with` context and I ran into this issue. Let me try the above where I explicitly close the cursor.

Comment: @swmfg I can't reproduce any problem when I try to connect to a remote database *without* a DSN. I noticed the `time.sleep()` too, which means the connection attempts aren't made in a tight loop. Have you tried connecting using `SERVER` instead of `DSN` ? The data source may contain settings that affect the connection

Comment: Ok here are the things I've tried. Neither connecting to database directly or wrapping cursor in a `with` context helped. The loop ran for hours when I reduce batch size to `ids = [(i, ) for i in range(100)]`. The `sleep(60)` was added to mimic some computation time in between calls to database but removing it didn't help.

Comment: Testing various insert size, `ids = [(i, ) for i in range(20000)]` ran into the above error at ~30,000-th iteration, whereas 15,000 didn't, and 100,000 error out within the first 100 iterations. So it seems like once the insert size crosses a certain threshold it will start running into the above error.